# How to get temporary path of client machine in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use Path.Gettemppath() to get temp path. But it returns server's temporary path. I want to store some data client side at client's temporary folder. How can I get temporary path?

Comment: To store files client-side, provide a link/button/etc. to download the file.  Let the client decide how and where to store it.

Comment: ASP.NET is a *server side* technology. What do you want to store at the client?

Answer (score 5):

You cant store anything clientside. You either have to use cookies or use HTML5's localstorage via Javascript. 
This is an obvious security measurement.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually i want to save one XML file at client side ! These XML file contains all Favorited products' details of particular client ! Is that possible ?

Comment: Any data can be stored permanently in your Database, or temporary in cookies.

Comment: @NoOne: Why does this need to be stored on the client?  Why not just store a user's "favorites" in a database on the server?  That's a considerably more common (and simpler, and more manageable) way of storing user data.

Comment: To story it in your database you have to make a callback to your server each time a user presses the favourite button. You can use Javascript to set cookies clientside.

Answer (score 0):

Access to your clients computer is not available as a security measure on every single machine.

You can save information client side using cookies, or use something novel like HTML5's localstorage (*don't recommend it though - not consistent*).

I would recommend storing the users favorite products on the database side, as a cookie can be easily erased and that is data a user would expect to *not* be temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, the browser (and JavaScript) are basically firewalled from accessing the client's system.  You need to either use some sort of ActiveX control, a Java Applet, Flash, maybe Silverlight, or take advantage of [HTML5 local storage](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/index.html) (if the browser supports it) to store information on the client.

You're trying to use server-side code to access something on the client, which is not possible.